# Unsure how a method works within a scala class

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand the add method in below class taken from book 'Programming in Scala - Second Edition'. 
Is this correct : 
The method 'add' takes defines an operator which of type Rational. I don't know what is occurring within the new Rational :

```
numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom,
denom * that.denom
```

How are numer & denom be assigned here ? , Why is each expression separated by a comma ?
Entire class :

```
class Rational(n: Int , d: Int) {

  require(d != 0)

  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)
  val numer = n / g
  val denom = d/ g

  def this(n: Int) = this(n, 1)

  def add(that: Rational): Rational = 
    new Rational(
        numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom,
        denom * that.denom
        )

  override def toString = numer +"/" + denom

  private def gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int = 
    if(b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That two expressions are the arguments to the `Rational` constructor, thus they will be the `private val`s `n` and `d` respectively. For example

```
class C(a: Int, b: Int)
val c1 = new C(1, 2) // here 1, 2 is like the two expressions you mention
```

The `add` method implements rational number addition:

```
 a     c     a*d     c*b     a*d + c*b
--- + --- = ----- + ----- = -----------
 b     d     b*d     b*d        b*d
```

where

```
 a = numer
 b = denom
 c = that.numer
 d = that.denom
```